# Can you tell me what is wrong with these tomato plants

Tags: vegetables

They have been producing very well and I have had probably 8 or so Tomatoes already and they are still blooming and still making Tomatoes but they look like crap! I live in Missouri and it has been very hot here already this year and I am just at my wits and I don't know what to do and I also had a question about my cucumbers they are producing like crazy also speckled yellow thanks

Comment: can you add a photo please?

Comment: Are these plants in the garden soil or in pots?  Have you used fertilizer?  What are your watering techniques?  Do you have access to shade cloth?  Reemay?

Comment: Did you prune them, or let them grow naturally? Do you have a picture? 2 questions 2 posts

Comment: @Barbara Are you still interested?  When you get a chance send more information as; were tomatoes and/or cucumbers grown in this soil last year?